# Can I change leaflet tile size?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I am using `leaflet` library for maps and layers. Leaflet divides visible map into tiles. Sometimes tiles are greater in number. My concern is to **reduce number of tiles** and **increase tile size** for some different purpose.I want to fetch Raster information in Json format instead of Raster images.

By default,tile size is 256x256. Can I change the tile size?

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `tileSize` option:

```
new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.example.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    tileSize: 512
}).addTo(map);
```

> Width and height of tiles in the grid. Use a number if width and height are equal, or L.point(width, height) otherwise.

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#gridlayer-tilesize

Comment: I did this but I still get tileSize = 256x256.